# How to make my code with for/if loop more efficient in R

Tags: performance, r

My code is structured so that I create an ellipse through my first three points of data. Then I go through each next row, and if the point falls outside the ellipse, I record the minimum distance between the point and ellipse. These points have datetime associated with it so I can only keep points 10 minutes old in my ellipse (so it doesn't get too big). The code works great until I have to process 100K+ of observations. Then the process time goes from minutes to hours. My question is, is there any part of my for loop portion of code that I can restructure to cut process time? I vectorized what I could (I think), and I know taking conditions out of for loop helps but now sure how to do it. Code below for reference. Any help is greatly appreciated.

````
library(sp)
library(cluster)
#create new empty column in dataframe
df$Distances <- NA

#get first three points and fit an ellipse around it
FlashPoints <- cbind(df$Lat[1:3],df$Long[1:3])
EllipseShape <- ellipsoidhull(FlashPoints)
EllipseShape

#get set of points that represent ellipse
EllipsePoints <- predict(EllipseShape)
EllipseGroup <- cbind(EllipsePoints[,2],EllipsePoints[,1])

#function to check if the next flashpoint (xp, yp) belongs to the ellipse with parameters a,b,... with tolerance eps
onEllipse <- function (xp, yp, a, b, x0, y0, alpha, eps=1e-3) {
  return(abs((cos(alpha)*(xp-x0)+sin(alpha)*(yp-y0))^2/a^2+(sin(alpha)*(xp-x0)-cos(alpha)*(yp-y0))^2/b^2 - 1) <= eps)
} 

#function to check if the point (xp, yp) is inside the ellipse with parameters a,b,...
insideEllipse <- function (xp, yp, a, b, x0, y0, alpha) {
  return((cos(alpha)*(xp-x0)+sin(alpha)*(yp-y0))^2/a^2+(sin(alpha)*(xp-x0)-cos(alpha)*(yp-y0))^2/b^2 <= 1)
}

#loop from row 4 to last row
for (i in 4:nrow(df)){

#get location of next point
nextFlash <- cbind(df$Long[i],df$Lat[i])

#Establish/Re-establish parameters
xp <- df$Lat[i]
yp <- df$Long[i]
x0 <- EllipseShape$loc[1] # centroid locations
y0 <- EllipseShape$loc[2]
eg <- eigen(EllipseShape$cov)
axes <- sqrt(eg$values)
alpha <- atan(eg$vectors[1,1]/eg$vectors[2,1]) # angle of major axis with x axis
a <- sqrt(EllipseShape$d2) * axes[1]  # major axis length
b <- sqrt(EllipseShape$d2) * axes[2]  # minor axis length


#Check to see if next point is outside the ellipse, then get distance. If it is, add to distance list
if((insideEllipse(xp, yp, a, b, x0, y0, alpha)==FALSE) && onEllipse(xp, yp, a, b, x0, y0, alpha)==FALSE){
  nextDist <- min(spDistsN1(EllipseGroup, nextFlash, longlat = TRUE))
  df$Distances[i] <- nextDist
    
#Omit points 10 minutes old from group
  movingGroup <- subset(df[1:i,], difftime(df$DateTime[1:i],df$DateTime[i],units = "mins")<10)
  movingTstorm
  FlashPoints <- cbind(movingGroup$Lat[1:i],movingGroup$Long[1:i])
  FlashPoints
  
  #Fit an ellipse around flashpoints
  EllipseShape <- ellipsoidhull(FlashPoints)
  EllipseShape
  
  #Get set of points that make an ellipse
  EllipsePoints <- predict(EllipseShape)
  EllipseGroup <- cbind(EllipsePoints[,2],EllipsePoints[,1])
} 
  
next(i)
}
}
```
````

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).